# How significant is this error in terms of context?

Tags: grammar, articles

I noticed that there is an article "the" before "one" in the following sentence. This sentence is from an affidavit.

*1.) I have known xyz for a long time;*

*2.) I know for a fact that xyz and abc refer to "**the**" one and the same person.*

How significant is this error in terms of context?

Comment: How are you judging significance?

Answer (score 0):

In context, it has no significance except to very slightly call into question the author's competence.

It's wholly true that *the* one and the same person is simply wrong, but that doesn't make it any way ambiguous.